# Updating an Eclipse Android project via Git - image resource not updating

Tags: android, eclipse, git, android-emulator

I am working with a team on an Android game. There was a graphics spritesheet resource that was created with an initial tile width of 96 pixels and later reduced to 64 pixels. On the author's computer the project runs correctly at the new dimensions but on my machine, even though the image has been updated to the new resolution, when I go into debug and call getHeight() on the BMP resource, it returns 96 and the animation displays incorrectly (gets clipped).

I have tried:
refreshing eclipse filesystem
re-cloning the project and creating a clean project in eclipse
starting eclipse with -clean
cleaning the build

The problem persists and I have run out of ideas. Please, how do I get get eclipse to uncache whatever crud its keeping somewhere and use the new image that's plainly sitting in the /res/ folder??

I am testing the project on the emulator. Running android api 2.1, level 7.

```
Bitmap bmp;
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blah);
```

Comment: Just to make sure, have you tried double clicking on the image file in Eclipse Package Explorer (opens an image viewer on Mac at least), and verified it's the image what you're expecting?

Comment: Yeah. Eclipse knows it's there and windows explorer agrees on the file system side. I did just realise that I can edit the image and still have the same problem with the dimensions... I just doodled all over the tilesheet in red and it shows up when it runs, but the dimensions are still buggered. My current suspicion is that it has to do with me running a different resolution emulator than the original author. I need to test that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "inScaled" flag when loading the Bitmap if you want to force the original size. I found this out the hard way when my [Open GL textures weren't showing up on larger screen devices](http://quirkygba.blogspot.com/2011/04/why-are-my-textures-not-showing-up-on.html).

Something like this should do it:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inScaled = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.my_image, opts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android automatically scales images in the resources folder for the screen resolution of the device. So even if the source image has a height of 64 pixels, there's no guarantee the .getHeight() will return 64.

Moral of the story: don't hard-code values for the sizes of images - use the accessor methods.